# Inside for loop take 1st and 5th element en each loop?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a data frame with starts and ends for date ranges of 5 days.

This the my function I'm using to create a list of date ranges:

```
from <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
to <- as.Date("2020-02-21")
d <- seq(from, to, by = "1 days")
n <- length(d)
chunk <- 5
f <- rep(1:((n %/% chunk) + 1), each = chunk, length.out = n)
head(split(d, f))
```

The elements look like:

```
head(split(d, f), 4)
$`1`
[1] "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" "2017-01-05"

$`2`
[1] "2017-01-06" "2017-01-07" "2017-01-08" "2017-01-09" "2017-01-10"

$`3`
[1] "2017-01-11" "2017-01-12" "2017-01-13" "2017-01-14" "2017-01-15"

$`4`
[1] "2017-01-16" "2017-01-17" "2017-01-18" "2017-01-19" "2017-01-20"
```

I need to take the 1st and 5th date of each element of the list to make my data frame. I'm trying to make a for loop to capture the starts (1st element) and the ends (5th element).

I'm trying to access them like this:

```
my_date_ranges <- split(d, f)

my_date_ranges[[1]][1] #first element start
my_date_ranges[[1]][5] #first element end
my_date_ranges[[2]][1] #second element start
my_date_ranges[[2]][5] #second element end
...
```

But when I try to loop the list like this:

```
for(i in my_date_ranges){
  print(my_date_ranges[[i]][1]) #this would be the starts
}
```

I get this error:

> Error in my_date_ranges[[i]] : no such index at level 1

Desired output:

```
starts       ends
1  2017-01-01 2017-01-05
2  2017-01-06 2017-01-10
3  2017-01-11 2017-01-15
...
n  2020-02-17 today-minus-1-day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, select the 1st element as 'start', 5th as 'end' to create the 'data.frame

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, f), function(x) 
        data.frame(start = x[1], end = x[5])))

head(out)
#    start        end
#1 2017-01-01 2017-01-05
#2 2017-01-06 2017-01-10
#3 2017-01-11 2017-01-15
#4 2017-01-16 2017-01-20
#5 2017-01-21 2017-01-25
#6 2017-01-26 2017-01-30



str(out)
#'data.frame':  230 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ start: Date, format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-06" "2017-01-11" ...
#$ end  : Date, format: "2017-01-05" "2017-01-10" "2017-01-15" ...
```

---

Or another option is instead of calling the `data.frame` inside each `list` element, extract the 'Date' separately and then do a final data.frame

```
lst1 <- split(d, f)    
out1 <- data.frame(start = do.call(c, lapply(lst1, `[`, 1)), 
            end = do.call(c, lapply(lst1, `[`, 5)))

i1 <- is.na(out1$end)
out1$end[i1] <- out1$start[i1]
```

Or if the OP wanted to get the `last` item if there are fewer items

```
i1 <- lengths(lst1) < 5
out1$end[i1] <-  do.call(c, lapply(lst1[i1], tail, 1))
```

---

If we use OP's code, one option would to be to initialize a `list` or `data.frame` with `NA` and then update the object on each loop run

```
out2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(my_date_ranges),
       ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "end"))))

for(i in seq_along(my_date_ranges)) {

    out2$start[i] <- list(my_date_ranges[[i]][1])
    out2$end[i] <- list(my_date_ranges[[i]][5])
 }
out2$start <- do.call(c, out2$start)
out2$end <- do.call(c, out2$end)
```

Comment: Chaning 4 to 5 in the indexing works. Otherwise your answer misses some days.

Comment: @OmarGonzales  Sorry, earlier I misread as `4` instead of 5. Updated

Comment: the list's last row shows: `2020-02-20       <NA>` as probable the last list element has fewer than 5 elements. How can we put the last available item here?

Comment: @omarGonzales You can use `na,locf0` from `zoo`.  updated `library(zoo)#
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, na.locf0)`

Comment: @OmarGonzales Do you need `i1 <- is.na(out1$end);
    out1$end[i1] <- out1$start[i1]`

Comment: @OmarGonzales or make a condition where the lengths are less than 5 and update accordingly.  `i1 <- lengths(lst1) < 5;
out1$end[i1] <-  do.call(c, lapply(lst1[i1], tail, 1))`  I updated the answer